# What's the connection between the deep ones and the Cult of the Sleeper in the Pyramid?

Tags: charles-stross, laundry-files

Minor spoilers for Stross' Laundry Series follow.

In *The Jennifer Morgue*, we are introduced to the Deep Ones. In *The Apocalypse Codex* they are mentioned multiple times to be somehow connected to one of the Cults that wants to awaken the Sleeper in the Pyramid.

However, in *The Jennifer Morgue* the Deep Ones are presented as being basically sane and having as much to lose from CASE NIGHTMARE GREEN as humanity. So what's the deal? Did I miss something, are they different groups, is it referenced anywhere clearly?

Answer (score 6):

Presumably the deep ones also have the equivalent of the human cultists like CLUB ZERO and the Golden Promise Ministry.

There must be an equivalent OCINTEL organisation down below as well.

Comment: what's CLUB ZERO?

Comment: Didn't want to give away any spoilers - CLUB ZERO is the code name for one one the cults that Mo gets called to deal with.